# Incorrect number or type of argument when using Jlink to call setAccessible

Tags: java

I am trying to use Java reflection to access stateVector from the following package:

```
package org.yakindu.scr.lightswitch3;

public class Lightswitch3Statemachine implements ILightswitch3Statemachine {

protected class SCInterfaceImpl implements SCInterface {

    private boolean operate;

    public void raiseOperate() {
        operate = true;
    }

    protected void clearEvents() {
        operate = false;
    }
}

protected SCInterfaceImpl sCInterface;

private boolean initialized = false;

public enum State {
    main_region_off,
    main_region_on,
    $NullState$
};

private final State[] stateVector = new State[1];
```

This works well until I try to call setAccessible:

```
Needs["Jlink`"]
InstallJava[];
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[] <> "lightswitch3.jar"];
m = JavaNew["org.yakindu.scr.lightswitch3.Lightswitch3Statemachine"];
sv = m@getClass[]@getDeclaredField["stateVector"];
```

This returns False, as expected:

```
sv@isAccessible[]
```

This fails:

```
sv@setAccessible[True]
```

with: Java: Method named setAccessible defined in class java.lang.reflect.Field was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The argument was True.

This also fails:

```
sv@setAccessible[MakeJavaObject[True]]
```

with: Java: Method named setAccessible defined in class java.lang.reflect.Field was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The argument was « JavaObject[java.lang.Boolean]».

Note that there is a static and non-static version of setAccessible:

```
Methods[sv, "setAccessible*"]

{
 {"void setAccessible(boolean) throws SecurityException"},
 {"static void setAccessible(java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[], \
boolean) throws SecurityException"}
}
```

So I also tried this:

```
list = JavaNew["java.util.ArrayList"];
list@add[MakeJavaObject[{sv}]];
java`lang`reflect`Field`setAccessible[list, MakeJavaObject[True]]
```

However it fails as well: Java: The static method java`lang`reflect`Field`setAccessible was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The arguments, shown here in a list, were {« JavaObject[java.util.ArrayList]»,« JavaObject[java.lang.Boolean]»}.

This issue may have something to do with this (unanswered) question: [How to call a java method that takes a boolean (not Boolean)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59768/how-to-call-a-java-method-that-takes-a-boolean-not-boolean)

Comment: A very uneducated guess would be that there is a [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) at play and it throws `SecurityException`, which `JLink` possibly interprets in the same way as if the method with this signature does not exist. It should be possible to test this theory by using a different classloader to load your class (which would not have a security manager attached).

Comment: I'm a complete novice at Java and JLink. How do I use a different class loader?

Answer (score 5):

After reviewing this again [How to call a java method that takes a boolean (not Boolean)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59768/how-to-call-a-java-method-that-takes-a-boolean-not-boolean)

I noticed that both setAccessible methods required a primitive boolean, not a Boolean object. Thus, all of the attempts above with MakeJavaObject[True] were destined to fail.

The following still failed:

```
java`lang`reflect`Field`setAccessible[list, True]
```

However, replacing the java object for the array (list) with {sv} worked:

```
java`lang`reflect`Field`setAccessible[{sv}, True]
sv@isAccessible[]
True
```

I'm not sure why {sv} works, when the array object does not. I'm still also not sure why sv@setAccessible[True] does not work.

For completeness, especially since I found nothing online on how to do this from MMA, here is code that shows reflection working. Note that this is simple two state machine (off, on) with a single action, operate, that toggles between the two states.

```
Needs["Jlink`"]
InstallJava[];
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[] <> "lightswitch3.jar"];
m = JavaNew["org.yakindu.scr.lightswitch3.Lightswitch3Statemachine"];
sv = m@getClass[]@getDeclaredField["stateVector"];
java`lang`reflect`Field`setAccessible[{sv}, True];
m@init[];
m@enter[];

s1 = sv@get[m];
s1[[1]]@name[]

"main_region_off"
```

Raise the Operate action, which should turn the light on

```
m@raiseOperate[];
m@runCycle[];
s2 = sv@get[m];
s2[[1]]@name[]

"main_region_on"
```

Reset the machine back to s1 and test

```
sv@set[m, MakeJavaObject[s1]];
s3 = sv@get[m];
s3[[1]]@name[]

"main_region_off"
```

Raise operate again to be sure the machine still works with the forced state change

```
m@raiseOperate[];
m@runCycle[];
s4 = sv@get[m];
s4[[1]]@name[]

"main_region_on"
```

Comment: Interesting. I just checked using a different classloader that my theory was wrong, and was about to comment on that.

Comment: The `setAccessible` instance method fails because JLink has generated the wrong signature for it -- it appears to have copied the signature of the like-named static method by mistake. Perhaps JLink is getting confused because there are four overloads of that method in scope, two on `Field` and two on the superclass `AccessibleObject`. This looks like a bug to me.  The methods on AccessibleObject have correct signatures. The `ArrayList` object fails because the signature requires a plain Java array, not a list object.